# Изменение шрифтов на странице. Русские буквы соединяются.

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Делаю сайт по шаблону, http://user1148450.atservers.net/index.html
но почему в заголовках русские буквы все "слиплись", как это поправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Файл style.css, строка 29. Для h3 задано правило:

```
letter-spacing: -2px;
```

P.S. Возможно оно нужно где-то в других местах и чтоб его не удалять, допишите классу lead (строка 49):

```
letter-spacing: normal;
```

Comment: @Deonis спасибо, работает, а сколько лучше поставить?

Comment: @Колямбий, с маленьким опозданием, но я уже дополнил это в ответе.

Comment: @Deonis все не разберусь, как тут благодарить за помощь?

Comment: @Deonis применил letter-spacing: normal; но это не сработало для h4, мне везде эту строчку (letter-spacing: normal;) значит прописать нужно?

Comment: @Колямбий, повторюсь - если по умолчанию для тегов были прописаны такие правила, значит они где-то могут быть нужны. Как исключения, к тем же заголовкам, вы можете добавлять класс, где устанавливаете нужный интервал между символами.